# Is there any modern Indo-European languages with synthetic passive form

Tags: list-of-languages, comparative-linguistics, passive

Which modern IE language(s) have synthetical passive form(s)? Latin did have, but it is not a modern one.

Comment: Requests for lists are generally OT on Stackexchange.

Comment: worth noting that PIE did not have a passive. It had an active and a "middle". In some branches (like Latin) the middle shifted to a passive, and in others (like Greek, Indo-Iranian, and later still North Germanic) a new passive developed

Comment: What is a modern IE language?

Comment: @user6726 No. There is even a [[:tag:list-of-languages]] for such question (with some guidance what kind of languages lists are on topic)

Comment: @Lambie it seems pretty clear to me. A modern language (i.e. one spoken in the present day) that is in the IE family (i.e. it is Indo-European)

Comment: @Tristan Hmm. I though they were just Indo-European languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages

Comment: @user6726 Bit ambiguous whether you mean "off" or "on," no?

Comment: @Lambie not specifying "modern" would include extinct IE languages (or earlier stages of surviving ones), like Latin, Sanskrit, Hittite, or Tocharian. The fact OP specified "modern" seems to be intended to exclude those

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll try to give as complete a list as I can, going (surviving) branch by (surviving) branch.

- Albanian

  - Standard Albanian has a medio-passive voice sometimes described as a passive. It continues the PIE middle, just as the Latin passive did.
- Armenian

  - Old Armenian had a medio-passive (continuing the PIE middle) but this has been lost in the modern language.
- Balto-Slavic

  - The PIE middle seems to have already been lost in the earliest stages of all these languages.
  - East Slavic has a neo-middle formed with the clitic -*ся* "-sja". This can have passive semantics, but can also be reflexive or reciprocal. It derives from the earlier reflexive pronoun **sę* which remains a reflexive pronoun in the rest of Slavic. Compare North Germanic.
- Celtic

  - A passive voice continuing the PIE middle is attested in Gaulish & Old Irish.
  - The Insular Celtic languages (both the Goidelic and Brythonic languages) have various impersonal or autonomous verb forms. These are prototypically understood as impersonal, but can have passive senses. Depending on tense it may continue the Old Celtic passive or stem from various participles.
- Germanic

  - A passive voice continuing the PIE middle is attested in Gothic, and in the other Germanic languages solely in the irregular verb **haitaną* "to be called" (whence Modern German *heißen*). This verb has since been either lost or switched to a typical active inflection in all surviving languages.
  - North Germanic has a neo-middle formed with the clitic -*s* or -*st*. This can have a passive, impersonal, reciprocal, or reflexive sense. It derives from the earlier reflexive pronoun **sek*. Compare East Slavic.
- Greek

  - Ancient Greek retained a medio-passive sense for the PIE middle, but innovated a new passive voice. This does not survive into the modern language. The medio-passive is retained however.
- Indo-Iranian

  - Like Greek, Indo-Iranian retained a medio-passive sense for the PIE middle, but innovated a new passive voice.
  - I am not familiar with the details, but a quick overview found synthetic (or at least *morpho*syntactic) passives for: Gujarati, Kurdish, Marathi, & Rajasthani. This is likely far from exhaustive.
- Italic

  - Latin had a passive continuing the PIE middle, but this does not survive into the modern Romance languages.

So that would be: **Albanian**, **East Slavic**, **Insular Celtic**, **North Germanic**, **Greek** and **various Indo-Iranian languages** (from both the Indo-Aryan and Iranian subbranches) with forms that are often described as passive, although some of these are more properly medio-passive than true passive.

I have excluded most non-finite passive forms (e.g. passive participles) here, as these are extremely widespread. The Insular Celtic impersonal forms are included however as they appear for each tense and function as if they had a null person as subject, rather than simply being unmarked for the subject's person as is typical for non-finite forms.

Comment: Irish and Scottish also have a pseudo-passive called the autonomous form, which is synthetic. Originally, it more precisely states simply that an action takes place, without specifying the subject (and it also still does this), but under the influence of English and its heavy use of actual passives, it has also been used with actual passive meaning for several centuries. For example, Irish _itear_ (from _ith_ ‘eat’) means ‘eating is taking place’ and is autonomous, but _itear an bia_ ‘the food is eaten’ is pretty passive, and _itear an bia acu_ ‘the food is eaten by them’ even more so.

Comment: And of course, Modern Greek retains the inherited synthetic mediopassive, which functions much like the North Germanic neo-passive in being both passive, reciprocal, reflexive and deponential – so if you include North Germanic and East Slavic in the final list, you should probably include Greek as well.

Comment: from what I've read, in continental north germanic at least the neo-middle is (typically) a genuine passive rather than a middle. I have added Greek and Irish+Scottish Gaelic though

Comment: The neo-passive is also quite common as reflexive (_vi ses_ ‘see you’ [= we will see each other], _de slås_ ‘they’re fighting’ [= they hit each other], _de mødtes_ ‘they met [each other]’) as well as an impersonal form that’s somewhere between active, middle and passive (_de arbejder_ ‘they’re working’ vs _der arbejdes_ ‘work is being done; people are working’). Its use as a true passive is actually decreasing, having become more marked as formal over the past century or so (as the analytic passive with _blive / bli_ + past participle has increased in colloquial use).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet interesting! I will edit to take that into account

Comment: I am not too familiar with either Welsh or North Germanic, but it seems to me that the Welsh impersonal (non-past *siaredir* 'is spoken/will be spoken/one speaks', and past *siaradwyd*) has roughly the same claim to be included in this list as the North Germanic *-s/-st*.

Comment: @Pilcrow added. Seeing as there are distinct impersonals for each tense, I'm reasonably happy calling that finite as well (albeit certainly less finite than the personal forms)

Comment: @Pilcrow I had a sneaking suspicion Welsh would have them too, like Irish and Scottish, just couldn’t be bothered checking before. Their forms look similar as well, with past tenses using something ultimately based on the Indo-European _*-tó-_ adjective (≈ past participle) and the rest ending in _-r_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet a bit of further looking shows similar forms in Breton & Cornish, so it seems to be pretty general to Insular Celtic. I couldn't find reference to it in Manx, but I'm reasonably happy ascribing it to Insular Celtic in general at this stage

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm assuming the -r forms continue the PIE middle (in some form)

Comment: I believe so, yes. The Irish/Scottish forms continue the 3sg of the Old Irish passive, which was a fully-fledged mood, and certainly the primary present passive 3sg ending _-tar/-tir/-thar/-thir/-dar/-dir_ semi-directly continues the PIE middle ending _-tor_ (through an intermediate form something like _-tor-et-i_, with a presentive _-i_ and a particle _-et-_ that appears to have fossilised in place after the first tonic element in the clause, i.e., the verb or a preverb). The rest is a bit more complex, if memory serves, but definitely involves the middle.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In Swedish there is actually a distinction in both spelling and pronunciation for the reflexive form of _slå_. It's _Spiken slås av hammaren_ [=The nail is hit by the hammer.] but _Barnen slåss._ [=The children are hitting (fighting) each other.]. In the past tense they are both spelled _slogs_ but the reflexive form is pronounced with a short o. In the perfect tense they are indistinguishable though (_slagits_).

Comment: As far as I know _slå_ is the only verb for which this distinction is made and it's sometimes used as an example to highlight the distinction in meaning of the two forms. I guess you could argue that the reason they are different is because _slåss_ has also shifted in meaning from just hitting to the more general (physical) fighting.

Comment: @jkej It’s the same in Danish, at least in the present tense: they’re both spelt _slås_, but the sense ‘is hit’ is pronounced /slɔːˀs/, while the sense ‘fight’ is pronounced /slʌs/. The past tense is _sloges_ /sloːəs/ for both, and Danish doesn’t do the perfect for true passives at all anymore, so only the ‘fight’ sense (which is on its way to becoming a separate, deponent verb) has perfects at all. Danish and Norwegian also have the doublet _synes_ ‘is inspected [of cars]’ vs _synes_ ‘thinks, is of the opinion that’, where one sense has shifted enough to more or less become a separate verb.

Answer (score 10):

The North Germanic languages do! These examples are from Norwegian, but basically the same thing happens in both Danish and Swedish, and apparently also in Faroese and Icelandic.

In Norwegian, the present tense active is marked by the suffix -er. But transitive verbs can also take -es, meaning that the verb is passive.

- Jeg lager mat *I make food*
- Maten lages *The food is being made*

Comment: this passive is in fact present in all the modern North Germanic (Scandinavian) languages! It has its origin in the reflexive pronoun being suffixed to the verb (and does not continue the Proto-Indo-European middle), and in Old Norse still had this reflexive sense, before gradually shifting to its modern passive sense

Comment: Isn't _synes_ the passive of a different verb? I thought that _se_ has a regular passive _ses_...

Comment: @jogloran is correct. _Synes_ is the mediopassive of _syne_, not _se_, though it generally acts as an active verb. The mediopassive of _se_ is _ses_ (reciprocally as in _vi ses_ ‘see you’ or actually passive as in _dette ses tydelig_ ‘this is (~ can be) clearly seen’). Also, intransitive verbs can take mediopassive forms as well, most commonly found in impersonal constructions (_jeg arbeider på X_ ‘I’m working on X’, _det arbeides på X_ ‘work on X is being carried out’).

Comment: And of course, _mutatis mutandis_, the mediopassive in _-s_ is also found in Danish and Swedish, while Icelandic and Faroese have retained the older form in _-st_.

Comment: @jogloran and Janus. Oh yes, you are both correct. I will update the answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Some varieties of Norwegian have forms ending in *-s* and forms ending in *-st*. Are you able to comment on the difference between these forms?

Comment: @Omar Very true, I didn’t think of that. I’m not 100% sure, but I _believe_ those are generally the ‘Nynorsk-like’ dialects, the ones that most closely resemble original Norwegian (which belonged to the West Scandinavian branch). The reduction of the _-st_ to _-s_ is an East Scandinavian feature that spread into Norwegian through Danish influence, and some western dialects resisted. The older form may also have survived in some other dialects, but by and large I think it corresponds to the dialects that might still be considered West Scandinavian.

Comment: Basically, Danish and Bokmål use -es, Swedish uses -as, Nynorsk uses -ast. Spoken Norwegian (when featuring passive voice at all, many speakers never use it) is on a spectrum, most often some kind of -es or -æs or -as. Only particularly old-fashioned Western rural dialects and hardcore Nynorsk speakers really pronounce a clear -ast.

Answer (score 7):

In Ukrainian and Russian, you can form the passive voice form of practically any transitive verb by adding the reflexive particle *-ся* to the active voice form of the verb. Historically, this particle is a weak form of the impersonal reflexive pronoun *себе* (Ukr.) / *себя* (Ru.) “oneself”:

- *Я готую їжу*. “I am making food.”
- *Їжа готуєть**ся***. “The food is being made.” (lit. “The food is making itself”)

Such forms with *-ся* are officially considered passive, see meaning 3 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F#Verb), although adding that particle to a verb is rather word building than conjugation, *готувати* “to make” and *готувати**ся*** “to be made” are different lexemes. Besides, both Ukrainian and Russian have the ‘real’ passive voice formed by “to be” + the past passive participle, but this kind of the passive voice is used only in the past and future since the present tense of the verb “to be” is not normally used in the two languages. As a result, in the past and future tenses two parallel passive forms are possible, analytic and synthetic, the former usually with the perfective meaning and the latter imperfective:

- Їжа була приготована. “The food was made.”
- Їжа готувала**ся**. “The food was being made.”

Comment: Reflexive verbs Slavic in general. The difference is just in how close is the binding of the enclitic. *Vařím jidlo.* *Jídlo se vaří.* However, that does not mean that all reflexives are passive. Even in your link it is just point 3 or 3. The difference should probably be made xlear more explicitly.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава — You're right, the verbs with that enclitic can be not only passive, but also reciprocal and reflexive (and probably even deponential). Still, since this very question is exclusively about the passive voice, I see no need to explain _all_ the shades of meaning of the Slavic verbs with the reflexive enclitic, within the framework of this very question only their passive meaning is of some importance, the rest is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Punjabi and Sindhi both have synthetic passive conjugations for verbs, formed by infixing and shift of stress from the stem to the infix.

An example from Punjabi:

ਖਾਵਣ کھاوݨ (ˈkhā.vaṇ) gerund, “to eat”

ਖਵੀਜਣ کھویجݨ (khaˈvī.jaṇ) gerund, “to be eaten”

ਖਾਂਦਾ کھاندا (ˈkhān.dā) imperfect participle, “eats”

ਖਵੀਂਦਾ کھویندا (khaˈvīn.dā) imperfect participle, “is eaten”

The passive conjugations of verbs in Punjabi are mostly fossilized archaic forms although there are a handful of loan verbs to which the pattern has been applied. In Sindhi the formation of passives is more regular and broadly applicable.

Answer (score 0):

What actually about English active participle “singing”, passive participle “sung”, as thus in lots of  modern IE languages?

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: "Synthetic" means (or at least entails) that the passive form does not involve an auxiliary verb. In English, it does: the passive form consists of the auxiliary verb *to be* plus a participle.

Comment: @Pilcrow But the passive participle can be used without an auxiliary, e.g."fried fish"

Comment: Sure, but this is not what linguists mean when they talk about a synthetic passive voice. They mean that the predicate in a passive sentence is synthetic (as opposed to analytic, i.e. involving an auxiliary construction), not that a passive participle can be used as an attribute of a noun.

Comment: @fdb typically when people talk about "a synthetic passive" they mean a finite verb, not non-finite ones (so not participles or infinitives). Whether they can head an independent sentence is a common test for this and would include things like the Latin passive, Celtic impersonal forms, and the North Germanic neo-middle, but not the passive participles common throughout Indo-European

Comment: @pilcrow that's poppycock, presupposed already in the answer. An auxillary itself is not a synthetic morpheme, but the way *'s* is often suffixed it is not uniquely analytical. At any rate, it says nothing about the verb form, only about the construction.

Comment: *Talking stupid shit, are you?* may be analyzed as a dependent clause in a verbal phrase headed by "are" but nobody says "A winner is you". People say "Carl, I'm dead", "Hi dead, I'm Carl". So as soon as you accept that, you get